# How can i save a folder using dot html so that it shows the html symbols?

Tags: html, directory

I recently installed visual studio code and I intend using it as my main text editor. But While trying to save a folder naming it index.html, I noticed it wouldn't highlight these tags <> to indicate that the folder is an html folder. What am I not doing right here please?#html

Answer (score 0):

you can only save files with dot html